# Is there something wrong with my CPU?

Tags: cpu, cooling

Just for Reference my build:

i5 4590 3.3 ghz

8 gb of 2400 mhz ram

Nvidia GTX 980

Simplified: cpu idles at 80 degrees celsius and goes over 100 degrees celsius during gaming. Is it my stock cooler or the cpu that is the problem?

Hey guys, I've been having some really bad performance issues pertaining to gaming on my computer, like ridiculously bad for the build I have.  So I took my computer in to a repair shop and they told me that my performance issues stemmed from my CPU overheating to over 100 degrees celsius when playing any kind of game and idling at around 80 degrees celsius which is as equally as ridiculous.  So they told me the solution was to purchase a new heatsink that is better than the intel stock cooler and that the problem should subside but I was wondering if maybe that it's not the cooler but the CPU because reaching 80 degrees celsius while idling is completely ridiculous and does not make a lot of sense to blame it completely on the stock cooler.

Comment: The stock cooler is more than likely the problem. I'd get an aftermarket cooler. That's a high idle and high stress temperature for sure. In the meantime you could try different thermal paste and make sure the cooler is making good contact with the CPU, and make sure your case has good airflow.

Answer (score 1):

They should have inspected the mounting of the heat sink and made sure it was operating properly. A new heat sink, if properly mounted, will probably solve your problem. They're cheap and the stock heat sink is mediocre. But seeing how bad your idle temperature is, something is clearly wrong with the way the heat sink is mounted or the fan is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Without a heat sink, modern CPUs will easily and rapidly climb to 80 degrees Celsius and higher.  This can also happen if the heat sink is somehow broken, came off its mount, wasn't installed with thermal compound properly, or has a failing fan.

The stock heat sink for Intel isn't especially good, but it's not so bad as to cause 80c temperatures, which means one of the above problems must have happened to it.  The repair shop could possibly fix it, but I wouldn't be surprised if they want to sell you a new one.  Even still, a new heat sink would be much better, if it's installed properly, and good ones can be had for under $30.